# I am working on codeigniter but unable to write code for controller

Tags: php, mysql, json, codeigniter

I want to send the message to agents about the total properties that his clients had, for this I am joining 3 tables.
I had agent id at agents table and total properties in `activity_search_log` .
so I got done with a model as below 
My code in **model** is:

```
public function agentsjoin(){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('agents ');
    $this->db->sum('prop_nums')
    $this->db->limit (100);
    $query=$this->db->get();
    $list=$query->result();
    return $list;
}
```

In controller, I want design code in such a way that and unable to write:

```
foreach(agent)
    if(properties > 0)
        send message;
    else
        no props exist to send message;
```

Comment: Please post the code you have already written for the model and controller

Comment: show your controller function code

Comment: what is on in $list ..??

Comment: public function agentmessage(){
        $this->load->model('agent_model');
        $res=$this->agent_model->agentsjoin();
        $res->agent_id;

        foreach(agent_id as $id)
            {
            echo $id;
        }

Comment: this is what i had written but unable to write

Comment: if(properties > 0)
send message;`enter code here`
else
no props exist to send message;   this is the way how i want to write in controller

Comment: how to add the numbers in prop_count cloumn in model

Comment: $this->db->sum('prop_count'); is this correct